# KDE 4.6.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: 10.10, kubuntu, kde

This is what I have done.
I Added kubuntu backport PPA for Ubuntu 10.10. After I installed the kde-standard package.

I then tried to login using KDE plasma workspace from xsession.

The problem is that when KDE starts and I can only see my old Gnome desktop. But I am sure KDE is running Gnome, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gives me the KDE's desktop search but the rest of the apps are defaulted to Gnome.

Then I tried installing the whole kubuntu-desktop package. But the same problem continues.

How can I resolve this issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See if by chance Nautilus is running, if you start it without any options - it starts desktop, as result everything starts to look as gnome.

Comment: I am not running a single command before this happens. Maybe some startup script doing this? but I dont know where to look for that.

Comment: you could try running 'ps axuf |grep autilus' as i do not know if that starts with capital N or not. Afterwards kill it. And yes, i thought that KDE while starting started Nautilus as startup process. You can check by starting 'System Settings'-> 'Startup and Shutdown'